# CV-qualifiers & references for concept requires parameters

Tags: c++, c++20

Suppose I have a `deserialize` function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T deserialize(const std::string& src);

// Specialized for various types
// ...
```

and want to define a `Deserializable` concept for types for which `deserialize` is specialized. Are there any difference between the following versions?

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept Deserializable = requires(std::string s) { deserialize<T>(s); };
// concept Deserializable = requires(std::string& s) { deserialize<T>(s); };
// concept Deserializable = requires(const std::string s) { deserialize<T>(s); };
// concept Deserializable = requires(const std::string& s) { deserialize<T>(s); };
```

If `requires` was similar to a normal function, then I'd expect the 1st (resp. 3rd) version to be identical to the 2nd (resp. 4th) version, as the name `s` inside a normal function body is an lvalue. However, I've seen the standard library use reference types as `requires` parameters, for example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range):

```cpp
template< class T >
concept range = requires(T& t) {
  ranges::begin(t); // equality-preserving for forward iterators
  ranges::end  (t);
};
```

which seems to suggest that reference vs. value matters.

More generally, do CV-qualifiers and references for `requires` parameters matter?

**UPDATE:** I came up with a [test](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/df5E341hT) to show that `requires` indeed seems to behave like normal functions:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void f(T&&, T&&) {}

template <typename T>
concept Foo = requires(int x, int& y, int&& z) {
    f(x, y);
    f(x, z);
    f(x, 123);  // won't compile: deduced int& and int
};

int main()
{
}
```

So it seems the `requires(T& t)` in the standard library example above is no different than `requires(T t)`. Is this always the case?

Answer (score 1):

If `T` is an rvalue **reference** type `U&&`, `T&` is `U&`, but that matters only if `decltype` or something like `std::forward` is used.  The only other formal difference is that it prevents the parameter from being **adjusted** to be a pointer if it’s an array or function type, which also rarely matters.

It may also be meant to avoid suggesting that a type is copyable/movable (as is often required for by-value *function* parameters).